# Can we do a proof by induction on something which looks like an infinite tree?

Tags: graph-theory, solution-verification, induction, order-theory

#### Introduction

I am used to applying proof by induction to ***infinite paths***.

An example of an infinite path is $Q = \left \{\,\,(\,k \,\,,\, k+1): n \in \mathbb{N} \cup \{0\}\,\,\right\}$

$$Q =\left\{\,\,(0 \,\,,\, 1), \,\,(1 \,\,,\, 2), \,\,(2 \,\,,\, 3), \,\,(3 \,\,,\, 4), \,\,(4 \,\,,\, 5), \,\,(5 \,\,,\, 6), \,\,(7 \,\,,\, 8)\,\cdots\, \right\}$$

Is a proof by induction valid if performed on an infinite tree?

#### Attempt to Define an infinite Path

Maybe a "*non-finite path*$\,$" is simply a subset $\smile$ of a strict total ordering $<$ such that:

- there is nothing sandwiched in-between two nodes which have an edge between them.

  - $\forall x,z \in V, x \smile z \implies \forall y \in V,  \text{ NOT } x < y < z$
  - Equivalently, $\forall x,y \in V, x < y \text{ and } y < z \text{ implies not } x \smile z$
- Every node in the path has one incoming edge and one outgoing edge (except the start of the path)

  - *one outgoing edge means*$\dots\dots$   $\quad \forall x \in V: \exists \text{ unique } y \in V : \,\, x \smile y$

---

For any non-finiite set $V$ and $E \subseteq V \times V$,  $P = (V, E)$ is a "***infinite path***" if and only if all of the following hold:

- The path has a starting point, beginning, or left-most node.   $\quad \exists y \in V: \forall x \in V,\,\, (x, y) \not\in E$
- Every node has one incoming edge and one outgoing edge (except the start of the path)

  - *one outgoing edge means*$\dots\dots$   $\quad \forall x \in V: \exists \text{ unique } y \in V : \,\, (x, y) \in E$
  - The in-degree of $x$ ($\mathtt{indeg}(x) = 1$) for all $x \in V$ except the first node in the path.
- The path is connected

  - there exists a strict total ordering consistent with path $P$, and for every strict total ordering, if $(x, z)$ is an edge in path $P$, then there is nothing between $x$ and $z$ in the strict total ordering

    - For any strict total order $P^{\prime} = (V, E^{\prime}), \quad \text{ if } E \subseteq E^{\prime} \text{ then } \forall x,y \in V, (x, y) \in E^{\prime} \text{ and } (y, z) \in E^{\prime} \text{ implies } (x, z) \not\in E$
    - $P^{\prime} = (V, E^{\prime})$ is a ***strict total order*** if and only if all of the following conditions are satisfied:

      - $(V, E^{\prime})$ is *irreflexive*.

        - $\forall a \in V, (a, a) \not\in E^{\prime}$.
      - $(V, E^{\prime})$ is *transitive*

        - $\forall a, b, c \in V a < b \text{ and } b < c \implies a < c$
      - $\forall a, b, c \in V, \text{ if } a \neq b$, then $a < b$ or $b < a$

---

That definition of "*infinite path*" was a mess.
Let us move on, shall we? $\dots\dots\quad$

#### Proof by Induction on an Infinite Path

Anyway $\dots\dots$

> Let $P = (V, E)$ be an infinite path on vertex set $V$
>
> $\forall x \in V$, $x$ is black
>   if and only if
> both of the following are true:
>
> - The start of the path (left-most node) is black
> - $\forall x, y \in V, \text{ if } (x, y) \in E \text{ and } x \text{ is black then } y \text{ is  black}$.

## Is a proof by induction valid if done on an infinite tree?

#### Definition of Infinite Tree

An "***infinite tree***" is an ordered pair $T = (V, E)$ such that:

- $V$ is a non-finite set.     $\quad \not\exists m \in \mathbb{N}: \exists \text{ bijection between } V \text{ and } \{k\in\mathbb{N}: 1 \leq k \leq m\}$
- The transitive closure of $E$ is a strict total ordering (similar to strictly-less-than for real numbers)
- The tree has exactly one root node, or source node (starting point, beginning, whatever )   $\quad \exists y \in V: \forall x \in V,\,\, (x, y) \not\in E$
- There is a surjective function $F$ from $V-\mathtt{root}(V)$ to $V$ such that $(x, y)$ is an edge if and only if $x = F(y)$. In other words, every node has exactly one parent node, except for the root node.
- The tree is connected

#### Example of an infinite tree

Suppose we have tree $T = (V, E)$ such that:

- The empty set is the root node.
- $V = \{A \subseteq (ℕ \cup \{0\}) \text{ such that } A \text{ is finite }\}$
- For any $A \in (ℕ∪ \{0\}) $, $(A, A \cup \{\mathtt{max}(A)+1\}) \in E$
- For any $A \in (ℕ∪ \{0\}) $, $(A, A \cup \{\mathtt{max}(A)+2\}) \in E$
- There are no other edges in the tree except those described above.
- $(ℕ ∪ {0})$ denotes the set of all subsets of $ℕ$

#### The Method of Induction on an Infinite Tree

> Let $T = (V, E)$ be a tree-like thing on non-finite vertex set $V$
>
> $\forall x \in V$, $x$ is black
>   if and only if
> both of the following are true:
>
> - The root of tree $T$ is black
> - $\forall x, y \in V, \text{ if } (x, y) \in E \text{ and } x \text{ is black then } y \text{ is  black}$.

To reiterate, is a proof by induction valid if done on an infinite tree?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, because the set of all nodes between an arbitrary vertex $v$ and the tree's root is a path.  In other words:

$$\forall x \in V ~ (\{ v \in V \mid v \lt x \} \text{ is well ordered with the root of the tree as the least element}).$$

By the way, I often find it useful to think of induction using the well-ordering principle.  In other words, if your proposition is false, then by the well-ordering principle there must be a minimum counterexample.  Prove that the root of the tree isn't a counterexample, and then use the inductive step to prove that any counterexample necessarily leads to a smaller counterexample, thereby contradicting the minimality of any possible counterexample.  Thus, there can be no counterexamples and the proposition must be true.